# Assign new values to entire row in DataFrame Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**How to assign new values to each row?**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

[image: dataset sample]

```
for i in np.arange(len(dataset)):
    if dataset['comment_num'].iloc[i] == 0:
        dataset['words'].iloc[i] = 0
        dataset['characters'].iloc[i] = 0
```

is working.

But it seems that neither

```
dataset[['words', 'characters']].iloc[i] = [0, 0]
```

nor

```
dataset[['words', 'characters']].iloc[i] = dataset[['words', 'characters']].iloc[i].replace([''],'0')
```

works.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `dataset.loc[dataset['comment_num'].eq(0), ['words', 'characters']] = 0`

Answer (score 1):

You can use loc function:

```
dataset.loc[i, ['words', 'characters']] = 0
```